# how to insert the data of following work day in a range

Tags: vba, excel

i need to change the value of all the cells in my range for "portfolio + the following working day data". So for instance, today I would need to have the values of my range as "portfolio05042015". I have already set my range as you can see

```
Sub SelectNonBlanks()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A10000")
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
End Sub
```

So now, i just need to change their values. I would really appreciate your help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value to selected range, for example:

```
Selection.Value = "portfolio" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy")
```

If you want nextworkday you can use this function or find someting using google:

```
Function NextWorkday()

Select Case Weekday(Now, vbMonday) ' - Monday is first day of work you can change this for example for vbSunday. In this example every Saturday and Sunday are holiday
Case 5
NextWorkday = Now + 3
Case 6
NextWorkday = Now + 2
Case Else
NextWorkday = Now + 1
End Select

Holidays = Array("14042015", "16042015") 'your holidays list, format ddmmyyyy

Index = 0

For Each ArrMember In Holidays
    If Format(NextWorkday, "ddmmyyyy") = Holidays(Index) Then
    NextWorkday = NextWorkday + 1
    End If
Index = Index + 1
Next

NextWorkday = Format(NextWorkday, "ddmmyyyy")
End Function
```

Your sub with NextWorkday function

```
Sub SelectNonBlanks()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A10000")
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select

Selection.Value = "portfolio" & NextWorkday

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, but then i am using the current date. would you know how to put the next working day date?

Comment: thanks david, but why case 6 is necessary? if its friday we use case 5, if not case else, right?

Comment: in case you forgot to run on Friday and Saturday launched :)

Answer (score 0):

If your selection is correct:

```
For Each myCell In Selection
    myCell.Value = CStr(myCell.Value) & " " & CStr(Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy"))
Next myCell
```

Comment: It changes original value to a string